# How to use a variable from a numeric counter in a ".bat" file without conflict with the other variables?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I wrote a code in `.bat` that writes the count of numbers in a variable. This counter is inside a `for`, of course! The problem is that when I run the `.bat` file the window closes immediately, even if I use`pause`. When I run this same code on a file that has only this code, the counter works fine. What could be the cause of the error?

```
set /a var=0
for /r c:users\user\desktop\ %%file IN (*.mp3*) do (
  set /a var+=1
)
echo %var%
```

Comment: `set /a var=0` is unnecessary unless var was previously defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for` loop variables can only be a single letter. `%%file` is not a valid variable name, so you get an error. (Run the script from the command line instead of double-clicking it to see the error `%file was unexpected at this time`.) Simply change the loop variable to `%%f`.

```
set /a var=0
for /r c:users\user\desktop\ %%f IN (*.mp3*) do (
  set /a var+=1
)
echo %var%
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an alternative (probably faster when there are many files):

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /s /b "c:users\user\desktop\*.mp3*" ^|find /c /v ""') do set "var=%%a"
echo %var%
```